# Problema "CORS" usando AJAX y PHP

Tags: cors

Tengo este codigo de JQUERY:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
listarDetalle();

});
function listarDetalle(){
     var accion="listar";
       var URLprotocol = window.location.protocol;
    $.ajax({
     
            type: "POST",
            url: URLprotocol+"//gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php",
            data: { "accion":accion}, 
            dataType:'json',
        
            error: function(){
                alert("error petición ajax");
               
            },
            
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
             
                                   
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        
                var newRow =
                    "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].idp + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].nombre + "</td>" 
                    "<td>" + data[i].marca + "</td>" +
                    "<td>" + data[i].cantidad + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input type='radio' id='"+data[i].idproducto+"' name='seleccion'/></td>"+
                    "</tr>";
                $(newRow).appendTo("#ticket tbody");                 
       
    
               
            
        
  

        } }
        
}).fail( function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

  if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

    alert('Not connect: Verify Network.');

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

    alert('Requested page not found [404]');
  

  } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

    alert('Internal Server Error [500].');

  } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

    alert('Requested JSON parse failed.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

    alert('Time out error.');

  } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

    alert('Ajax request aborted.');

  } else {

    alert('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

  }

});;

};
```

Y obtengo este error:

**Pedido de Origen cruzado bloqueado: La Política de mismo origen no permite leer el recurso remoto en http://gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php. (Razón: el pedido de CORS fue rechazado).**

Probe con:

```js
dataType:'jsonp',
```

Que encontre en una web, pero si hago eso me dice que fallo la carga del script. La verdad no se que hacer.
Adjunto imagenes de google chrome de los encabezados..la direccion aparece bien digamos es:

**http://localhost/gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como veran da el error 302 en procesoDetalle.php como que el recurso fue movido pero no entiendo.

Lo llamo desde otro script y todo bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar he de comentarte que esta línea es innecesaria:

```
 url: window.location.protocol + "//gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php"
```

Si quieres mantener el esquema (`http:` o `https:`) basta con no indicarlo:

```
 url: "//gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php"
```

Por otro lado, las reglas de [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control) (o también conocidas como de [intercambio de recursos de origen cruzado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercambio_de_recursos_de_origen_cruzado)) impiden que puedas acceder a los recursos de una página externa si ésta no autoriza a tu sitio web a hacerlo.

Por defecto todas las consultas dentro de un mismo origen (misma URL o **Same Origin Policy**) se presuponen seguras y no hacen uso de CORS para su validación, sólo las consultas a orígenes (o URLs) externas.

Para ello el navegador realiza una [consulta previa (preflight request)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Preflight_peticion) mediante el [método HTTP `OPTIONS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS).

Es precisamente esa consulta previa la que te ha fallado y, por lo tanto, se presupone prohibido el acceso a ese API externo.

Una forma de implementar la respuesta a esa consulta previa podría ser agregando el siguiente código al comienzo de tu script PHP:

```
<?php
/* Permitimos a cualquier origen acceder a este API de manera remota */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  /* No debe ejecutarse el resto del script mediante la consulta OPTIONS previa */
  die();
}
```

**OJO**: Este código permite el acceso a tu API **desde cualquier URL**.

---

Si deseas restringir el acceso al API a un reducido número de URLs entonces deberías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
<?php
/* Listado de URLs (orígenes) que tienen acceso al API (sin / al final) */
$autorizados = [
  'http://www.origen1.com',
  'https://www.origen2.es',
];
/* Comprobamos que el origen esté en el listado de orígenes permitidos */
if (
  isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
  && in_array($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'], $autorizados) === true
) {
  /* Sólo autorizamos el origen validado */
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
  /* No debe ejecutarse el resto del script mediante la consulta OPTIONS previa */
  die();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Probe de las dos formas en el archivo php que llamo desde AJAX y me da el mismo error, el pedido fue rechazado. Pero con las otras llamadas desde AJAX no ocurre.

Comment: Tenía una pequeña errata en el código, mira las modificaciones que he hecho y prueba si te funciona. Yo las pruebas las he hecho en este gist y me funcionan: https://gist.github.com/ojgarciab/258b5456d3767ead8989893953af2859

Comment: Sigue dando ese error, no se puede modificar el archivo .ini de php? Por otro lado el pedido falla hacia http://gestionweb/includes/php/procesoDetalle.php osea no dice localhost por ej.. En mi pc tengo una ipfija detras del router, y la antepuse a gestionweb y me dice: encabezado CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' faltante.

Comment: Tendría que ver qué cabecera "origin" crea para hacer la petición. ¿Has probado a autorizar todos?

Comment: Si. Probe poner la instruccion con el *(asterisco) y nada...queda igual. Voy a probar tomar un ip automaticamente.

Comment: ¿Es lo primero que tienes en el archivo PHP? ¿Antes de cualquier otra cosa que tengas (incluso `include`s o similares)? Es especialmente importante que el envío de cabeceras se haga antes que el envío de cualquier contenido de la web. ¿Podrías decirme qué cabeceras retorna la petición o bien podemos hablar en un chat de stackoverflow para intentar hacer una conexión remota y ver las cabeceras en directo?

Comment: si..primero esta el codigo que me diste. Abri un chat por favor

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82146/discussion-on-answer-by-oscargarcia-problema-cors-usando-ajax-y-php).