# script js no funciona en laravel 7

Tags: javascript, laravel

tengo este código js que funciona en un servidor web, al que accedo directamente con un ip y me muestra algunos datos. Dicho servidor posee un lector de temperatura que se puede acceder desde http://192.168.0.5/temp, devolviendo un texto plano, con el valor de la temperatura actual, sin ningún estilo, solo html. Este codigo funciona excelente en un archivo html haciendo peticion ajax asincrono, pero no puedo hacerlo andar en laravel, como si fuera poco se suma una dificultad mas. Antes yo accedia al url 192.168.0.5/temp, eso en el mismo servidor, pero el servidor de laravel es otro servidor que tendria que hacer la peticion get supongo a otra url que seria el ip del servidor de temperatura. Dejo el codigo que no puedo hacer andar en laravel. gracias amigos!

```
 setInterval(function ( ) {
   var blabla = new XMLHttpRequest();
   blabla.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = this.responseText;
     }
   };
 blabla.open("GET", "/temp", true);
 blabla.send();
 }, 10000 ) ;
```

En la consola del navegador me devuelve un error de este tipo:

GET http://192.168.0.250/temp net::ERR_FAILED
(anonymous) @ control:490
setInterval (async)
(anonymous) @ control:481
control:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.0.250/temp' from origin 'http://egg.test' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Editado.

Coloque esta porcion de codigo en public/index.php

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token , Authorization');
```

Me sigue dando el mismo error!, tambien lo puse en el controlador, par probar nomas pero no tuve exito!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Problema "CORS" usando AJAX y PHP](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/189223/problema-cors-usando-ajax-y-php)

Comment: no pude hacerlo andar de esa forma triby

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que intentaste en Laravel para enviar los encabezados y permitir el acceso.

Comment: gracias triby, ahora edito